# Get the value from array and check value is present or not

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array look like this

```
$langs = Array
(
    [source] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Arabic
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Azerbaijani
                )

        )

    [target] => Array
        (
            [0] => Azerbaijani
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Amharic
                    [1] => Burmese
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => English
                    [1] => German
                )

        )

)
```

Now I want to search a value from target key. So I have my code look like this

```
$target = array();
array_push($target, 'English'); // want to search from the above array so I made it push to array
foreach( $langs['target'] as $langs ) {
    if(in_array( $target, $langs )) {
        echo 'Got the value';
    }
    else {
        echo 'not got values';
    }
}
```

But its not working. So can someone kindly tell me how to get the values? Any help and suggestions wil be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: it doesn't make sense, `array_push($target, 'English');` why do you need an needle which is an array? you just need to search for the existence of a string right?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  $got=false;
foreach( $langs['target'] as $lan=> $langs) {

            foreach( $langs as $lang=> $lan){
                if($target[0]==$lan ) {
                    $got=true;
                    break;
                }else{
            continue;
        }

            }
    }
if($got){
    echo "got it";
}else{
    echo "not found";
}
```

**NOTE:** in_array does not work for multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this recursively, iterating through each of the arrays, as in_array does not search recursively.

Try this:

```
$target = array(
'Azerbaijani',
array('Amharic','Burmese'),
array('English','German')
);

function search_recursive($find, $where) {
foreach ($where as $element) {
if (is_array($element)) {
if (search_recursive($find, $element))
return true;
}
elseif ($find == $element) {
return true;
}
}
return false;
}

if (search_recursive('English', $target)) echo "FOUND";
else echo "Not Found";
```

This has not been thoroughly tested, so make sure you test properly.